# What does thg drag_move do? How is it different from hg add and hg remove?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

As a user of [TortoiseHG](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/), I have been wondering how the `thg drag_move` command works which mimics (or implements) the functionality behind the "HG Move versioned item(s) here..." context menu entry.

The help entry obtained via `thg -v help drag_move` gives:

```
thg drag_move SOURCE... DEST

move the selected files to the desired directory
```

As far as I understand, it must execute the following sequence (or similar) under the hood:

```
hg forget SOURCE
mv SOURCE DEST
hg add DEST
```

But if I do that manually (outside of TortoiseHG), it (naturally) doesn't associate DEST with SOURCE, it rather treats them as individual, unrelated changes.

If I use the GUI or the `thg drag_move` command, it keeps the history of these entries the same, at least within TortoiseHG I can still see SOURCE's history when I look at DEST's history after the move.

Is this a TortoiseHG extension to Mercurial or is there a `hg` option to achieve the same "natively"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: You can use `hg move OLD NEW` to achieve the same functionality as `thg drag_move`.

Thg is using `hg move` under the hood when it's doing drag_move (see the [run.py](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/src/6d346452a2fd6c0043442b5a620808dbab2cb0c4/tortoisehg/hgqt/run.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#run.py-604) and [quickop.py](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/src/6d346452a2fd6c0043442b5a620808dbab2cb0c4/tortoisehg/hgqt/quickop.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#quickop.py-321) sources for details).

Hg move is the right way of renaming or moving a file in Mercurial because it's tracking the operation, as it says in his help message (hg help mv):

```
rename files; equivalent of copy + remove

Mark dest as copies of sources; mark sources for deletion. If dest is a
directory, copies are put in that directory. If dest is a file, there can
only be one source.
```

Comment: Thanks +1 for the hint about `hg mv`, which I wasn't aware of. I'll accept your answer if you care to include a bit more detail and link to some documentation about it.